# Url openconnection

Tags: android, http, url, httpurlconnection

I have been looking at the Java Doc, and could not clarify about the validity of the URLConnection method.

My Question is that if I want to download multiple files whose URL only differ by the file name, then do I still need to open connection on each URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is Yes you are required to open a connection on each URL. As far as I know there is no way to connect to a base URL and then request to read separate file names. Maybe there is a way to do this, but all of the methods in `URLConnection` (ie `getInputStream()`) takes no parameters - so I don't see a way of requesting a specific resource other than opening a new connection.